# UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python for Bulgarian cyrillic

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I receive UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position
>   0: invalid start byte.

There aren't any cyrillic symbols in the data. Is it because of setting for Bulgarian cyrillic? Do you know what to set?

I tried with next:

> df= pd.read_csv('kgb.csv',header=0,encoding ='cp1251')

But I receive the same error.

Comment: try `encoding = "ISO-8859-1"`

Comment: It doesn't work again.

Comment: I saw what is the error. It was because it was header=1, not header=0 and there are data on the seqond line in the file.