# decoding error while reading csv files from folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading headers of csv files from a folder.

code:

```
#mypath = folder directory with the csv files
for each_file in listdir(mypath):
  with open(mypath +"//"+each_file) as f:
     first_line = f.readline().strip().split(",")
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte
```

Environment:

```
Spyder, Python 3
```

Not able to understand the encoding error since I have not done any encoding.

Comment: Check the following link if it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540170/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python-for-bulgarian-cyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using encoding while opening the file in the with condition. I tried the below code and worked fine for me. Please try different encoding's and see if any of it works

```
for each_file in listdir(path):
    with open(path +"//"+each_file,encoding='utf-8') as f:
        first_line = f.readline().strip().split(",")
        print(each_file ,' --> ',first_line)
```

Also, check this link for checking file encoding for CSV. hope it helps.

[How to check encoding of CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177069/how-to-check-encoding-of-a-csv-file)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

try using single slash '/'

please try using

```
with open(mypath +"/"+each_file) as f:
```

Another problem may be the CSV file contains Unicode, not UTF8. It would be easy if you post sample of CSV file too.

Answer (score 0):

The built in `os.path.join` provides a convenient way to join two or more paths, without worrying about Platform specific slashes '`/`' or '`\`'.

```
import os

files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
    with open(os.path.join(path, file), encoding='utf-8') as f:
        first_line = str(f.readline()).strip().split(",")
        print(file, ' --> ', first_line)
```